# Why all the roots of $x^n -1$ are multiple over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if $p|n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is a claim in the book "Abstract algebra" in one of the examples, can someone explain this please ?

I know that the derivative of this polynomial is identically $0$ so there is a multiple root, but why all the roots are multiple ?

Comment: Which book exactly?

Comment: @lhf - http://www.amazon.com/Abstract-Algebra-Edition-David-Dummit/dp/0471433349

Comment: Denote $P = X^n-1$. If $P(\lambda) = 0$, then you also have $P'(\lambda) = 0$ (because $P' = 0$), so $\lambda$ is a root of order at least two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=kp$ then $x^n -1= (x^k -1)^p$, because $x\mapsto x^p$ is an automorphism. So, the roots of $x^n -1$ are exactly the roots of $x^k -1$ and appear with multiplicity at least $p$.

Comment: I don't follow, can you please add more details ?

Answer (score 1):

Because $x^{dp}-1 = (x^d-1)^p$